# Play music across pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So currently I have a simple template I use across all pages. It goes something like this:

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <h1>My website</h1>
  <div id="audio-player">
    <audio controls>
      <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
  </div>
  <p>Content</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Where the `<p>Content<p>` is located, is the different content I have. One page has the history of our music group, and the other page has images of our instruments, for example, between the `<p>` tags.

The thing is, every time someone navigates between the pages on our site, the music stops. How would I link the `<div id="audio-player">` to load across the site without stopping the music? I heard there is a way of using AJAX to do this sort of thing, but I cannot find a way to implement it so that the `<div>` appear on all site and never unloads?

Comment: If you want to keep the audio playing while navigating through the site, the simplest solution would be to use a 'single-page app'. This means that when a user wants to navigate, the page won't reload, instead, you'll have Javascript load and display the requested page without reloading the page.

Comment: Or he can use an iFrame, the user would then navigate trough the iFrame and the music player would be outside the iFrame.

Comment: But with a single page app/iframe, the URL doesn't change. What if one wants to bookmark the different content? They'd have to bookmark the whole page and find it again once they load the page again.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes oh, I completely forgot about iFrames. That is a much simpler solution.

The URL does change. AngularJS is an example framework that changes the URL as you navigate.

Comment: @JeremyZh With an SPA, using AngularJS, the page CAN be bookmarked depending on how the routing is setup

Comment: Here is a music player that may interest you it is easy to install and will play seamlessly thoughout your site.  http://scmplayer.net/

Comment: @JeremyZh try pushstate to change url with single page app- maybe less of a learning curve than Angular: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState

Comment: or simply use location.hash, and `onhashchange`